# How can I find all combinations of numbers in a list that's equal to a certain value in python?

Tags: python

So this project I'm working on is trying to find all combinations of wins, ties, and losses in a season given the number of games the team played and how many points they earned.

So far I've only figured out how to get one combination but I'm unsure how I would go about getting all the combinations.

**A win is 3 points, a tie is 1 point and a loss is 0 points.**

An example of this would be the team played 20 games and scored 30 points my output should be: 
**10-0-10 

9-3-8 

8-6-6 

7-9-4 

6-12-2 

5-15-0**

This is what I currently have:

```
def process_seasons(seasons):

    # Repeating this until all seasons have been processed
    for i in range(len(seasons)):
        games = seasons[i][0]
        points = seasons[i][1]
        curSeason = i + 1
        gamesWon=gamesTied=gamesLost=0

        # default cases
        if (points % 3 == 0):
            gamesWon = points/3
            process_season(curSeason, games, points, gamesWon, gamesTied, gamesLost)
        if (points == 0):
            gamesLost = games
            process_season(curSeason, games, points, gamesWon, gamesTied, gamesLost)

        # combination cases

    pass
```

And this is how the function is called:

```
# format of list: [[season-1-games, season-1-points], [season-2-games, season-2-points], etc.]
soccer_seasons = [[1, 3], [1, 1], [1, 0], [20, 30]]
process_seasons(soccer_seasons)
```

Comment: What results are you getting now and what errors have you run into?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 1):

So, in this case specifically, the first solution (most wins = fewest games worth points) would fairly trivially be `wins = total // 3`, `ties = total % 3`, `losses = games - wins - ties`

Obviously, if we have `losses < 0` then we fail out here and return the empty list.

Otherwise, you can use this first solution and iterate:

```py
wins -= 1
ties += 3
losses -= 2
```

Which doesn't change the total points of the season, or the total number of games played, until you get either `wins < 0` or `losses < 0`

In code:

```py
def enumerate_season_records(games_played, points_earned):
  """Returns a list of tuples in the form (wins, ties, losses)"""
  wins = points_earned // 3
  ties = points_earned % 3
  losses = games_played - wins - ties
  possible_season_records = []
  while wins >= 0 and losses >= 0:
    record = (wins, ties, losses)
    possible_season_records.append(record)
    wins -= 1
    ties += 3
    losses -= 2
  return possible_season_records
```

Note that this easy solution is possible because the point values work out nicely. The general case is NP-hard (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
def get_comb(games, points):
    games_list = [i for i in range(games+1)]
    return [i for i in product(games_list, games_list, games_list) 
            if i[0]*3 + i[1] == points]

>>> get_comb(20, 30)
>>> [(4, 18, 0),
     (4, 18, 1),
     (4, 18, 2), ...
```